# Set Image On Another View's UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to create a sort of 'settings' page, and I am having a hard time switching the background image of my original view. The code, so far, is:

```
-(IBAction)switchBackground:(id)sender {
ViewController *mainView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
mainView.displayedImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];;
}
```

Perhaps I can get some pointers?

Thanks, all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new `mainView` object each time you call `switchBackground` method. You must change the background of an existing object to see the change happen.

From your code it is hard to say where `switchBackground` method is located. `ViewController`?

If it is located in the view controller then all you have to do is:

```
self.displayedImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

**EDIT**

As per your comment.

When you want to change the image of an object of class A from class B you can do it in two different ways:

**1. Through reference to an object**

this is the settings initializer which on creation gets the pointer to your existing mainView

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)ViewController *mainView;

- (id)initWithMainViewController:(ViewController*)vc {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.mainView = vc;
    }
    return self;
}

-(IBAction)switchBackground:(id)sender {
    mainView.displayedImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
}
```

**2. By posting local notification through NSNotificationCenter.**

```
-(IBAction)switchBackground:(id)sender {
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"changeImage" object: [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
}
```

Now in your ViewController listen to the notification and react

in the init method in ViewController

```
- (id)initWithMainViewController:(ViewController*)vc {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeImage:) name:@"changeImage" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)changeImage:(NSNotification*)notification{
    self.displayedImage.image = (UIImage*) notification.object;
}
```

Comment: It's located in Settings.m

I tried ViewController.displayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]; but it wouldn't find "displayImage". I'm trying to change the image of ViewController (my main view--it's a two-view program).

Comment: In order to change the image in another class for witch you don't have a reference is not possible. You must have a reference to an existing view or use NSLocalNotification to change it. I will update my to show what I mean.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking forward to it.

Comment: Geez. Thanks for helping me out. I really appreciate it. You're awesome. I can't get it to work, though. If I put "@property(nonatomic,assign)ViewController *mainView;" in Settings.h it says it's an 'Unknown type name' and asks me if I meant UIViewController.

Comment: You have to import the ViewController class to make it work. `#import "ViewController.h"`

Comment: That did the trick, but now I have another problem. I switch views using `-(IBAction)switchView:(id)sender{
    ViewController *mainView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    mainView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:mainView animated:YES];
 }`

and, now I see (thanks to you), it's creating a new main view. Eh.. I'll try to learn some more before wasting your time and come back. Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of areas where stuff can go wrong. I can answer one question at a time. Pls go over the docs and if you get stuck post on SO.